# Find my Phone as a shortcut

Tags: ios, shortcut, find-my-iphone, shortcuts-app, find-my

My wife constantly misplaces her phone.

Is there any way to make a shortcut in iOS (or macOS) to enable a one-touch solution to find her iPhone? (I can see her phone in the Find My app).

Answer (score 2):

I have a family iCloud plan, and everyone is on the list. So I saw the option in the Shortcuts app that mentioned that I can add it as a shortcut.

If you go into the Shortcuts app and look under the Gallery tab, you might see an topic to add to "Show the location of" for your wife's phone.

But I think you can also directly just ask Siri to find your Wife's phone. I've done that with my oldest daughter's phone sometime as well.

Comment: I've also found Siri to be the fastest way to find the phone. As long as you know the name of the phone (which you can see in the Find My app), you can just ask Siri to find it.

Answer (score 0):

Because you can see her in FindMy, you can use the following steps:

1. Use FindMy to locate her device. (this will place the action on the menu)
2. Open Shortcuts app.
3. Add the short cut name. In my case (Locate Wife)
4. Click "+ Add Action"
5. Scroll down to find the action that was created by step 1.
6. Select it. In my case (Show the location of Mommy's iPhone)
7. Press the play button to test.
8. Navigate back to Shortcuts app tap the x to save the "Locate Wife" short cut.

You can use this technique to add many different kinds of shortcuts by changing your action in step 1.